# How do I change the DKIM length in Sendgrid?

Tags: sendgrid

We need to set the DKIM key length in SendGrid to 1024.

I have looked through the sendgrid management portal in Settings, Sender Authentication.

Where is the setting for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently SendGrid defaults to 1024 bit key length, so you will not need to adjust anything.